# Open and closed sets of a topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

Consider a set $X = \{a , b, c \} $ with topology $T = \{ \phi , \{a\} , \{b,c\}, X\}$.  It's closed sets are $\phi , X , \{a\} , \{b,c\}$. These are closed sets so there complement must be open i.e. it must be contained in $T$. Can someone tell me the compliments of these closed sets other then of $\phi$ and $X$.

Comment: I don't think your $T$ is a topology, it is not closed under union.

Comment: Let $S\subseteq T$ then the complement of $S$ in $T$ is $T\setminus S=\{t\,|\,t\in T,t\notin S\}$

Comment: Looks like to me the closed sets are prescisely the open sets.

Answer (score 1):

The topology are the open sets, by definition. In this special case, all open sets are also closed (as the complement of $\{a\}$ is $\{b,c\}$ and vice versa).